# I am creating a full stack application using react and python

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a full stack project that trains ml models based on the dataset given and algorithm chosen.
My code is giving errors. Can anyone please help me out?
This is Data.js file--

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import axios from 'axios';
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import './Data.css';

function Data() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [target, setTarget] = useState('');
  const [algorithm, setAlgorithm] = useState('');
  const [columnNames, setColumnNames] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleFileDrop = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    const selectedFile = acceptedFiles[0];

    if (selectedFile && selectedFile.type === 'text/csv') {
      setFile(selectedFile);
      setLoading(true);
      setError(null);

      Papa.parse(selectedFile, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: (result) => {
          const firstRow = result.data[0];
          if (firstRow) {
            const columns = Object.keys(firstRow);
            setColumnNames(columns);
            setData(result.data);
          } else {
            setError('CSV file is empty.');
          }
          setLoading(false);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          setError(`Error parsing CSV: ${error.message}`);
          setLoading(false);
        },
      });
    } else {
      setError('Please drop a CSV file.');
    }
  };

  const handleTrainModel = async () => {
    if (!file || !target || !algorithm) {
      alert('Please select a CSV file, target variable, and algorithm.');
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('target',target);
    formData.append('algorithm',algorithm);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate', {
        algo_name: algorithm,
        filepath: file.name,
        target_var: target,
        model_kwargs: {},
        // Add other parameters from your ModelSchema as needed
      });

      const responseData = response.data;
      setColumnNames(responseData.columns);
      setData(responseData.data);
      setResult(responseData.result);
      console.log("Success")
    } catch (error) {
      setError(`Error training model: ${error.message}`);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="split left-section">
        <Dropzone onDrop={handleFileDrop} accept=".csv">
          {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
            <div {...getRootProps()} style={{ border: '1px dashed  #383f51', padding: '20px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
              <input {...getInputProps()} />
              {file ? `Selected CSV File: ${file.name}` : loading ? 'Loading...' : "Drag 'n' drop a CSV file here, or click to select one"}
            </div>
          )}
        </Dropzone>
        <br />

        {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}

        {data.length > 0 && (
          <div className='Table'>
            <p>Data:</p>

            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
                    <th key={index}>{columnName}</th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                {data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                  <tr key={rowIndex}>
                    {columnNames.map((columnName, columnIndex) => (
                      <td key={columnIndex}>{row[columnName]}</td>
                    ))}
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        )}
        {columnNames.length > 0 && (
          <label>
            Target Variable:
            <select value={target} onChange={(e) => setTarget(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="">Select Target Variable</option>
              {columnNames.map((columnName, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={columnName}>
                  {columnName}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
        )}
        <br />
        <label>
          Algorithm:
          <select value={algorithm} onChange={(e) => setAlgorithm(e.target.value)}>
            <option value="">Select Algorithm</option>
            <option value="Logistic Regression">Logistic Regression</option>
            <option value="Linear Regression">Linear Regression</option>
            <option value="Random Forest">Random Forest</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <button onClick={handleTrainModel} disabled={loading}>Train Model</button>
      </div>

      <div className="split right-section">
        {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
        {result && (
          <div>
            <p>Accuracy: {result.accuracy}</p>
            <p>Precision: {result.precision}</p>
            <p>F1 Score: {result.f1_score}</p>
            <p>Confusion Matrix: {JSON.stringify(result.confusion_matrix)}</p>
            <img src={result.graph} alt="Graph" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Data;
```

I tried making changes to my code but the error won't go away .
This is the app.py file :

```
   from typing import Optional
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn

from model import GenericModel

app = FastAPI()

# Enable CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

class ModelSchema(BaseModel):
    algo_name: str
    filepath: str
    target_var: str
    test_size: Optional[float] = 0.2
    model_kwargs: Optional[dict]


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello, World!"}

@app.post("/generate")
async def generate_report(schema: ModelSchema):
    model = GenericModel(**schema)
    reports = model.run()
    return reports
# Add OPTIONS support for the "/generate" endpoint
@app.options("/generate")
async def options_generate():
    return {"allow": "POST, OPTIONS"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

This is the model.py file --

```
from typing import Optional
from pathlib import Path
import logging

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GenericModel:
    ALGO_MAPPER = {
        "Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression,
        "Linear Regression": LinearRegression,
        "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier,
    }

    def __init__(
        self,
        algo_name: str,
        filepath: str,
        target_var: str,
        test_size: float = 0.2,
        **model_kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        try:
            self.model = self.ALGO_MAPPER[algo_name](**model_kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            log.error(f"{algo_name} not supported!")

        self.filepath = filepath
        self.test_size = test_size
        self.target_var = target_var

    def read_file(self, filepath: str) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
        filepath = Path(filepath)
        if filepath.exists() and filepath.suffix == ".csv":
            df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
            return df
        else:
            log.error(f"Filepath: {filepath} does not exists or is not a csv!")

    def split_data(self, data):
        train_df, test_df = train_test_split(data, test_size=self.test_size)
        log.info(
            f"# Training examples: {train_df.shape[0]}, # Test Examples: {test_df.shape[0]}"
        )
        return train_df, test_df

    def create_report(self, true_values, predictions):
        report = {
            "accuracy": metrics.accuracy_score(true_values, predictions),
            "f1-score": metrics.f1_score(true_values, predictions),
            "confusion_matrix": metrics.confusion_matrix(true_values, predictions),
        }
        return report

    def train_model(self, features, labels):
        log.info(
            f"Training the model with {features.shape[0]} examples and {features.shape[1]} features."
        )
        self.model.fit(features, labels)
        return self.model

    def get_predictions(self, features):
        if not features.shape[1] == self.model.n_features_in_:
            log.error(
                f"Shape Mismatch!! Model trained with {self.model.n_features_in_} features,"
                f" received: {features.shape[1]} features"
            )
            return

        return self.model.predict(features)

    def run(self):
        data = self.read_file(self.filepath)
        if data is None:
            return

        if self.target_var not in data.columns:
            log.error(
                f"{self.target_var} not found in data. Provide exact column name."
            )
            return

        X_train, X_test = self.split_data(data)
        y_train = X_train.pop(self.target_var)
        y_test = X_test.pop(self.target_var)

        self.train_model(X_train, y_train)

        log.info("Getting Train Predictions...")
        train_predictions = self.get_predictions(X_train)
        log.info("Getting Test Predictions...")
        test_predictions = self.get_predictions(X_test)

        log.info("Getting Train Report...")
        train_report = self.create_report(
            true_values=y_train, predictions=train_predictions
        )
        log.info("Getting Test Report...")
        test_report = self.create_report(
            true_values=y_test, predictions=test_predictions
        )
        return train_report, test_report
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the url in axios.post incorrectly. Instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, you should add the `/generate` part, like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate`.

The corrected code would be:

```js
const handleTrainModel = async () => {
    if (!file || !target || !algorithm) {
      alert('Please select a CSV file, target variable, and algorithm.');
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate', {
        algo_name: algorithm,
        filepath: file.name,
        target_var: target,
        model_kwargs: {},
        // Add other parameters from your ModelSchema as needed
      });

      const responseData = response.data;
      setColumnNames(responseData.columns);
      setData(responseData.data);
      setResult(responseData.result);
      console.log("Success")
    } catch (error) {
      setError(`Error training model: ${error.message}`);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```